# Why am I getting a 302 redirect?

Tags: php, iis, redirect, deployment, wamp

I'm taking over a PHP project (devlopped by colleagues who left the company) and I'm facing a redirection problem on our validation environment.

On my Localhost there is no problem (I'm using Wamp), but on our validation environment (using IIS) I have a 302 redirect problem :

[image]

The user should be redirected to "interface_mapage.php", but he is systematically redirected to "admin_mapage.php"

I took a look at the code and especially for header location but nothing shocked me ... Any suggestion ?

Comment: Post your code. We've got nothing to go off otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I juste solved it.

The problem was coming from a header location :

```
<button type="submit" value="admin" id="bouton" name="admin" onclick=
                <?php header('Location : admin_mapage.php')?> >
```

Does anyone know why this code redirect to another page with IIS but not with Wamp ?